# Fails to build ogre on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: gazebo, ogre, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build step 2.1.2 from here: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

I've run: `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y` to the point where it tried to install gazebo and a dependency, ogre. The ogre build is failing, claiming it can't find freetype.
I've added a symlink as described on stackoverflow but then removed it as I should probably just `brew link` to get everything linked up. Using `brew unlink && brew link` doesn't fix my issue.

Here is my gist for ROS: https://gist.github.com/skotturi/42c2a58357c5c4c6951d

Here is my gist for when I `brew install -v ogre`: https://gist.github.com/skotturi/108f6e149b0e38424e7f

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, this thread suggested using a different version of freetype: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/885

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162956/fails-to-build-ogre-on-os-x-10.9.2/) by [sakotturi](https://answers.ros.org/users/17801/sakotturi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-09**:
Isn't this thread helpful? http://answers.ros.org/question/158271/ogre-build-fails-with-freetypeh-error-os-x-108-hydro/

**Comment by [sakotturi](https://answers.ros.org/users/17801/sakotturi/) on 2014-05-11**:
I installed matplotlib on this machine a couple weeks ago and came across that same thread :(

I tried removing the symlink to x11: `sudo rm /opt/x11/include/freetype2`
and then I tried building with the --HEAD version: `brew install -v ogre --HEAD`
This built in 26 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For mac users who have x11 installed, x11 comes with freetype and can cause some issues (not sure if this always happens or just in some cases). Especially if you do some symlinking to get python things to build.

I made sure to remove: `sudo rm /usr/local/include/freetype`
and : `sudo rm /opt/x11/include/freetype2`
NB: I haven't tested anything in x11 yet to see if this broke anything.

Then I built with the HEAD build of ogre using: `brew install -v ogre --HEAD`
It successfully built in 26 minutes (so give it some time)

---

Originally posted by [sakotturi](https://answers.ros.org/users/17801/sakotturi/) with karma: 26 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1